# Better way to achieve desired results for the following code

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So the scenario is that I have this following array as my input:

```
[
  {
    "failureMessage": "failed",
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4855"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "search"
  },
  {
    "failureMessage": null,
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4856"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "download"
  },
  {
    "failureMessage": "failed 2",
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4857"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "search"
  },
  {
    "failureMessage": null,
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4858"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "download"
  },
  {
    "failureMessage": "failed",
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4859"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "backgrounds"
  },
  {
    "failureMessage": null,
    "data": {
      "statusCode": 201,
      "body": {
        "id": "14975",
        "key": "KEY-4860"
      }
    },
    "testSetName": "backgrounds"
  }
]
```

the above array contains objects which hold the data regarding test cases

And I want an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "testSetName": "search",
    "testCases": ["KEY-4855", "KEY-4857"]
  },
  {
    "testSetName": "download",
    "testCases": ["KEY-4856", "KEY-4858"]
  },...
]
```

The above array contains objects and those objects hold the name of the test set(`testSetName`) and all the test cases which are part of this test set as `testCases`.

Now, my code is below:

```
  let results = testCasesObject.reduce(function (previousArr, currElement, currIndex) {

      if (previousArr.length === 0) {
        let obj = {testSetName: currElement.testSetName, testCases: []};
        obj.testCases.push(currElement.data.body.key);
        previousArr.push(obj);
      }
      else {
        let isAdded = false;
        for (let index = 0; index < previousArr.length; index += 1) {
          if (previousArr[index].testSetName === currElement.testSetName) {
            previousArr[index].testCases.push(currElement.data.body.key);
            isAdded = true;
          }
        }
        if (!isAdded) {
          let obj = {testSetName: currElement.testSetName, testCases: []};
          obj.testCases.push(currElement.data.body.key);
          previousArr.push(obj);
        }
      }

        return previousArr;
    }, []);

    console.log(results);
```

My code generates accurate results but I want to make it more efficient and I need help on this.

Comment: Have you tried posting the same question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have described the output I want and what it contains.

Comment: @ShivankVerma code review site is not as active as SO, I wanted to make sure that I'll get the answer. See the frequency of the questions asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa, i see only some dummy text there.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `testSetName` and reduce the array with a lookup for an already inserted item.

```js
var array = [{ failureMessage: "failed", data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4855" } }, testSetName: "search" }, { failureMessage: null, data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4856" } }, testSetName: "download" }, { failureMessage: "failed 2", data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4857" } }, testSetName: "search" }, { failureMessage: null, data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4858" } }, testSetName: "download" }, { failureMessage: "failed", data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4859" } }, testSetName: "backgrounds" }, { failureMessage: null, data: { statusCode: 201, body: { id: "14975", key: "KEY-4860" } }, testSetName: "backgrounds" }],            
    result = array.reduce((r, { testSetName, data: { body: { key } } }) => {
        var item = r.find(o => o.testSetName === testSetName);
        if (item) {
            item.testCases.push(key);
        } else {
            r.push({ testSetName, testCases: [key] });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve contains an algorithm often called "group by". There is a lodash implementation you can use: [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy)

This will give you an object indexed by "testSetName". Then you can go forward and `map` this to your desired structure.

```
const indexedByTestSetName = _.groupBy(data, item => item.testSetName)
// {search: [{testSetName: 'search', failureMessage: 'failed', data: {}}, ...]
const tests = Object.keys(indexedByTestSetName).map(key => ({
  testSetName: key,
  testCases: indexedByTestSetName[key]
)})
// [{testSetName: 'search', testCases: [{testSetName: 'search', failureMessage: 'failed', data: {}}, ...]}]
```

This is more efficient in terms of "lines of code", but how the performance compares is hard to guess. If you don't face millions of entries, I would not bother.

Comment: This certain that there won't be more than a thousand entries like this but still I wanted a better solution in terms of performance.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" :)